# Passing arguments to exec from python shell

Tags: python, shell

I'm using the python shell to launch a python script. I'm using the following command
exec(open("G:\Yowsup\src\yowsup-cli").read())

the problem is that i need to pass some arguments like this, but i don't know the right syntax
$ python yowsup-cli -c config.example -r sms

How to do it with Python 3?

EDIT
Please note that i don't know python and i'm not going to learn it, i just need to run and make tests on yowsup

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, you open up a file, read in its contents, and execute whatever those contents are?

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module, not `exec()` on the contents of the file. But why are you doing this from inside an interpreter to begin with?

Comment: Yes, that's right, @Wooble: unluckily i have no other chances than using python to run yowsup, i have no idea of what a module is or what a subprocess is. It's already a miracle i got this yowsup running...

Comment: Why ask a question about Python if you're against learning it?

Comment: Because it's the only way i have to send whatsapp messages... Bad choice by the yowsup developer! That would be easy make a .jar, just install JVM and double click..

Answer (score 2):

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then you can access arg in your script like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

They are stocked in `sys.argv` as a list (`sys.argv[0]` = `arg1` etc..)